# What is the difference between absteigen and aussteigen

Tags: verb, prefix, semantics

Both verbs seems to mean 'getting off from a vehicle'

Comment: Do you have any context where it seems to be the same in your understanding just the (english) origin uses different words (and there is a reason for that)? What did a dictionary tell you? "seems to mean" sounds not like "is listed as same with no other meanings"

Answer (score 4):

*Absteigen* denotes something where you are getting down, and (probably) comes from horse riding.  Besides horses, you use it for "horse-like vehicles" such as bicycles, motor cycles, or perhaps in a more literal sense for trucks that have a very elevated driver's cabin.  I would also use it for open carriages or trailers.

As @dennis mentioned, *absteigen* has also a very specific usage in mountaineering, but mostly for alpine or climbing-related movement: walls, via ferratas, etc.  You don't really use it for just hiking down a mountain.  For most other downwards movements, the prefix *herunter* is used (*von einem Dach, einer Leiter, ..., heruntersteigen; von einem Berg heruntergehen oder herunterwandern*; but: *der Abstieg vom Berg*).

*Aussteigen* marks exiting a "container vehicle", such as a car, train, bus, or truck if not focussing on the height.  It can also be used for planes and ships, but especially for ships I don't really like it, and would prefer something like *verlassen* (maybe because a large ship is closer to a house than a vehicle).

Comment: aussteigen can be used when talking about (small) boats; when it comes to ships it's verlassen (as you said) or "von Bord gehen".

Comment: Yeah, I had the same feeling. OK for a yacht, not so much for a cruise ship.

Answer (score 0):

*Aussteigen* means getting off from a vehicle, but *absteigen* reminds me of climbing down a mountain. *Absteigen* is also used to describe falling curves (as opposed to *ansteigen*).

I think the reason for this is *aus* means *out of* or *off* in the case of a vehicle, whereas *ab* means *downward*.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of „absteigen“:

- get off a bicycle: „Ich steige vom Fahrrad ab.“)
- a soccer club relegated: „Dresden ist aus der Bundesliga abgestiegen.“
- „Der Abstieg vom Berg war schwierig.“

Usage of „aussteigen“:

- when playing poker: „Ich steige aus.“